# Dockerfile for php to install magento 1.9.x on docker

Tags: magento-1.9, php, localhost, docker

I need to install magenot 1.9 on docker. Now, I have to create Dockerfile for php 7.2 with extensions which need magento.
Extensions:

- curl
- dom
- gd
- hash
- iconv
- mcrypt
- pcre
- pdo
- pdo_mysql
- simplexml

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ready made solutions out there

For example this

https://github.com/andreaskoch/dockerized-magento/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
installer:
  image: andreaskoch/dockerized-magento-installer
  environment:
    DOMAIN: dockerized-magento.local
    MAGENTO_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
    MYSQL_HOST: mysql
    MYSQL_DATABASE: magento
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
    ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
    ADMIN_FIRSTNAME: Admin
    ADMIN_LASTNAME: Inistrator
    ADMIN_PASSWORD: password123
    ADMIN_FRONTNAME: admin
    ADMIN_EMAIL: admin@example.com
    ENCRYPTIONKEY: 731aea833710535779fe8c7c49bc6c4d
  volumes_from:
    - nginx
  volumes:
    - ./config/installer/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - ./config/installer/magerun/n98-magerun.yaml.tmpl:/etc/n98-magerun.yaml.tmpl
    - ./config/installer/magento/local.xml.tmpl:/etc/local.xml.tmpl
    - ./config/installer/magento/fpc.xml.tmpl:/etc/fpc.xml.tmpl
    - ./config/installer/bin/substitute-env-vars.sh:/bin/substitute-env-vars.sh
    - ./config/installer/bin/install.sh:/bin/install.sh
  links:
    - "cache:rediscache"
    - "sessions:redissession"
    - "fullpagecache:redisfullpagecache"
    - "solr:solr"
    - "mysql:mysql"
  entrypoint: /bin/install.sh

nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  links:
    - "php"
  volumes:
    - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    - ./config/ssl/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem
    - ./config/ssl/cert.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key
    - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./config/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    - ./config/nginx/includes:/etc/nginx/includes
    - ./config/nginx/custom-locations:/etc/nginx/custom-locations
  volumes_from:
    - php
php:
  image: andreaskoch/dockerized-magento-php
  links:
    - "cache:rediscache"
    - "sessions:redissession"
    - "fullpagecache:redisfullpagecache"
    - "solr:solr"
    - "mysql:mysql"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.5
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
  volumes:
    - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
solr:
  image: andreaskoch/dockerized-magento-solr
cache:
  image: redis:latest
fullpagecache:
  image: redis:latest
sessions:
  image: redis:latest
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - "mysql:mysql"
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: "mysql"
    PMA_PORT: 3306
```

You know how to use docker-compose right?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

PHP itself is an image in this example

If you want to see inside

https://hub.docker.com/r/andreaskoch/dockerized-magento-php/dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

# Install
RUN buildDeps=" \
        libpng12-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        freetype* \
    "; \
    set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure \
    gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    gd \
    mbstring \
    mysqli \
    mcrypt \
    mysql \
    pdo_mysql \
    soap \
    zip \
    && apt-get update -qy && apt-get install -qy git-core \
    && cd /tmp/ && git clone https://github.com/derickr/xdebug.git \
    && cd xdebug && phpize && ./configure --enable-xdebug && make \
    && mkdir /usr/lib/php5/ && cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php5/xdebug.so \
    && touch /usr/local/etc/php/ext-xdebug.ini \
    && rm -r /tmp/xdebug && apt-get purge -y git-core \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove

# Configure
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/
COPY ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini

# Make sure the volume mount point is empty
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*

# Install magerun
RUN curl -o magerun https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netz98/n98-magerun/master/n98-magerun.phar && \
    chmod +x ./magerun && \
    cp ./magerun /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm ./magerun && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qy mysql-client
```

So using php:5.6-fpm

But hopefully from this you can see how either a) create your own image b) find an image running a newer version of php

*Update*

Meanbee have got a 7.2 image available

https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento

https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Just swap out 5.6 references for 7.2 references and you are ready to go

Comment: Thanks, you very helped me.